# Where to download Gmail Api?

Tags: api, gmail

i have to create a simple script which retrieves the mails from gmail account and then shows it to the user when user name and pass are supplied, the problem is am neither aware of gmail api and nor i know where to download it. i can't use any non official api, every help will be appreciated

**edit:**
i have to use php, just forgot to mention that btw i have found a solution here
http://petewarden.typepad.com/searchbrowser/2008/03/how-to-use-imap.html
there are still two problems here, that it is very slow and it retrieves the oldest first, can some one provide me with a solution for that or point me with any link?
i am noob

Comment: Did you *try* a search for "gmail api"?

Comment: you have not specified any programing language.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, i can't use a custom library, i have to do it myself it is a project and my language is php, thanks anyway :)

Comment: @user478903: It would have been useful to state that in your question, along with anything else you'd already found out. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints.

Comment: @user478903: why don't you state the required information with the question. I have posted an answer. try it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/

> Gmail supports the standard IMAP and SMTP protocols for accessing and
>   sending e-mail messages. The Gmail IMAP and SMTP servers have been
>   extended to support authorization via the industry-standard OAuth
>   protocol.

http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/oauth/

Answer (score 3):

There is no special api for getting mail from google servers. it uses the standard POP or IMAP protocols.

Not tested. Try it...

```
<?php
$mbox = imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX", "username", "password");

echo "<h1>Mailboxes</h1>\n";
$folders = imap_listmailbox($mbox, "{imap.gmail.com:993}/imap/ssl}INBOX", "*");

if ($folders == false) {
    echo "failed<br />\n";
} else {
    foreach ($folders as $val) {
        echo $val . "<br />\n";
    }
}

echo "<h1>headers in INBOX</h1>\n";
$headers = imap_headers($mbox);

if ($headers == false) {
    echo "Call failed<br />\n";
} else {
    foreach ($headers as $val) {
        echo $val . "<br />\n";
    }
}

imap_close($mbox);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no special API for retrieving mail. Mail is simply accessed via the standard [POP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol) or [IMAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol) protocols - you will need to build a client for one of these protocols, or simpler, just use a ready-made library that does it for you.

You can find the Gmail server information here: [POP](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287) and [IMAP](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78799).

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific?

The api information can be found here:

http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/